# Is there a way to dynamically wrap/intercept HtmlHelper extension methods. Think decorator pattern

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I would like wrap/intercept HtmlHelper extension methods (TextBox, Hidden, etc) provided in System.Web.Mvc.Html to enable reuse of the same Partial Views in 2 separate use cases.
Ex of Partial:

```
@model BlogEntry

@Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.Title)
@Html.TextAreaFor(t => t.Body)
@* Etc *@
```

The caller of the Partial will know the context (i.e. whether to override or leave the MS imp).

The reason for overriding are various. For example: to use in JQuery templates, where the output for the value attribute would be "${Title}" on the example above or to add Html5 meta data.

Comment: If you need to do this there is something wrong with your design and there is another way to achieve it.

Comment: Trying to achieve re-use the same html markup for client and server templates is bad design?

Comment: no, it is not. What is bad design is trying to intercept calls to standard html helpers.

Comment: I'd let the Action method teach the HtmlHelper about the context. Then it can decide what to render, and you can use the same views.

Comment: Why not create your own helper that wraps the MS helper and implements your custom logic? I really like the idea of switching the render to literal html or jQuery template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to intercept calls to the built-in helper extension methods. However you could write your own extension methods that do the right thing based on the context.

Comment: Intercept is the wrong word. I guess 1 issue I'm having is that the HtmlHelper functionality is implemented as Extension Methods, supposedly so that you can implement your own version of TextBox, etc, but there is no easy way to "override" or use your own CustomHelper without creating your own base view page and completely taking over.

As a hack I'm thinking of doing something like:
@{ Html = ViewBag.Html?? Html; } @* Where the ViewBag has CustomerHelper *@

I would prefer if MVC made it easy to use the same "EditorTemplates" with JS tempting such as jQuery Templates.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what your concerns are with adding your own extension methods -- why you'd have to "create your own base view page and completely take over." You can call your custom helpers in any page just as you would the built-in helpers:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
@Html.MyTextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
```

Furthermore, you can add some sort of flag parameter to your method to control whether it just executes the default functionality or something custom.

When you create your own extension methods, you'll have to either change the signature or the name of the method.

I used to use unique names, but ultimately found that I really wanted to be able to quickly discern my own implementations from the default, so I sometimes use:

```
@Html.Custom().TextBoxFor(…
@Html.Custom().TextAreaFor(…
```

Basically, you create one new extension method that takes an `HtmlHelper<T>` and returns a `CustomHelpers<T>`.

```
    public static CustomHelpers<TModel> Custom<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html)
    {
        return new CustomHelpers<TModel>(html);
    }
```

The `CustomHelpers<T>` class defines all of your own implementations:

```
    public class CustomHelpers<TModel>
    {
        private readonly HtmlHelper<TModel> _html;

        public CustomHelpers(HtmlHelper<TModel> html) { _html = html; }

        public MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
        {
            // because you have a reference to the "native" HtmlHelper<TModel>, you
            // can use it here and extend or modify the result, almost like a decorator;
            // you can get the "native" result by calling _html.TextBoxFor(expression)
        }
```

So, your "override" of `TextBoxFor` can receive a flag from your partial view to determine whether it returns the native result or something specific to the context.

Again, the `CustomHelpers<T>` class is entirely optional. You'll be adding a flag parameter or something similar to the signature of your custom helpers, so you won't collide with existing helpers.

The benefit it confers is to potentially namespace your helpers. You could have:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(…
@Html.JQuery().TextBoxFor(…
@Html.Mobile().TextBoxFor(…
```

Comment: It also helps to declare your custom helpers in namespace `System.Web.Mvc.Html`

Comment: Jay i really liked the way you implement helper methods.

Comment: The key is to re-use the existing views, without having to go thru and change them to custom. Currently, seems only possible thru hacks, see my comment to @marcind. Btw if you go custom, without inheriting from HtmlHelper, then everything needs to be re-implemented. Your technique works for other scenarios, but probably still better to inherit from HtmlHelper or HtmlHelper<T> IMHO.